# Spring security with basic auth: password is verified only the first time

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm using Spring security with Basic auth

I have the following configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
  }

  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();
    return http.build();
  }
}
```

And also a service implementing UserDetailsService:

```
@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService { //... }
```

This service reads the credentials from the database. I created some credentials username/password.

I'm using Postman to test it and I have the following results (in that order):

```
1) GET /endpoint using username/wrong_password -> 401
2) GET /endpoint using username/password -> 200
3) GET /endpoint using username/wrong_password -> 200
```

I expect the last call to return 401, but once it returns 200, it continues returning 200.

Any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/cookies/

Comment: It was that. I disabled "cookie jar" and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was not an Spring Security issue. I disabled the "cookie jar" from Postman and it worked.

Answer update based on comments: If you don't want to support sessions at all in Spring Security you should set the session creation policy to NEVER (more info [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-session))

Comment: Okay, but it sounds to me that you don't want to support sessions at all so perhaps you will want to set the session creation policy to NEVER. If Postman can trigger it, so can something or someone else. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-session

Comment: Its a better answer, please post it and I will chose it.